# Is there way to use High Quality mode via Google Photos API?

Tags: google-photos-api

I`m software developer and trying to upload some videos using Google Photo API, but I want to set up "High quality mode" of such videos programmatically.

So, the point is that my app must upload videos without user participation every 15 GiB.

Could anybody advice to me - how to do it?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

All media items uploaded to Google Photos using the API are stored in full resolution at original quality. They count toward the user’s storage.

check here: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/api-limits-quotas